# Can we send or return char in java webservices using JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am new to webservices.
I have some services which accept char as input parameter e.g char langPref etc.
When I am trying to expose that service it is throwing an exception.
Can we send or return char in web services ?

Comment: Provide more context. Are you talking about sending a single char in the message body, or a form parameter, or query param? How does your resource method look like? What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set an @Produces("text/plain") and return a String (cast from your char)

Likewise, an @Consumes should do the same trick for input.

(Having said that, you should probably emphasize the payload more. Just having chars as input/output is an indicator that your resource design is flawed)